# Chord progression (Em7,Bm7 what next)?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I’m working on my song and need help with chord progression.
The verse chord progression is : G, Cadd9, A7sus4 and Dsus4
I made a bridge with Em7 and Bm7 but I don’t know what need to come next (I sing the next chord but can find him LOL)

So I have 3 questions:
1. How can I find the key of song? (In most popular song I find the key by melody or simple chord progression)
2. How can I improve my knowledge about chord progression and make interesting chord progressions and not simple like this example at F major scale (F,A,Dm,Bb)
3. What need to be the next chord ? :)

Here’s the bridge:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o2Ie38Qfvi-YU5A7hiRov401oAMqih5n/view?usp=drivesdk

Sorry about audio quality I’m not at my home

Comment: "what chord would be good next" is highly opinion-based, and for the other things there are existing questions and answers if you search this site. If you try major and minor chords for all 12 notes, it will only be 24 things to try, and so it will take at most 30 minutes to cover all possibilities via brute force. :)

Comment: Sadly this site isn't really here to answer questions like this - particularly when we don't have much idea of the rest of the song. As piiperi says, there's 24 simple ones to try, and that's without using 7ths, sus, etc. You could always re-use a previous chord - that's what most songs actually do!

Comment: To be fair, I think that the BEST way to learn is by example ... but this site is a bit challenged in that regard. :/ Even uploading actual music examples is not supported. StackExchange is not really for learning, it's for building some kind of a "database of truths", but the problem is that people who have music-related issues are beginners and they cannot even explicate their questions as text. And even if they could, the terminology and everything would have to be somehow normalized, so the database could be _searched_. So the whole site is kind of designed to fail for many practical uses.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is: "any chord you want comes next." That may sound glib, but it isn't. Sure, there are convention chord changes, and you can use those conventions to say "what should come next," but you can *intentionally* play *against conventions* for effect, to surprise, or venture off into distance areas in a large composition.

From a conventional point of view...

> The verse chord progression is : G, Cadd9, A7sus4 and Dsus4

You can analyze that as (simplified) `I IV V7/V V`. That is pretty conventional. You have a tonic chord, pre-dominant harmony, and then the dominant. You could paraphrase that as just `I... V`.

> I made a bridge with Em7 and Bm7

Going from `G` to `Em` is `I` to `vi` or going to the relative minor. That's *very* conventional for a bridge or middle eight.

In terms of harmonic *contrast* going to the relative major or minor works, because you change the mode/quality and get a different mood.

But a bridge should also go somewhere. It's a bridge to *something.* The bridge first provides harmonic contrast, then it goes to some other tonal space. A conventional thing to do is play the dominant chord of wherever you are going, or some progression to the dominant in the key you are going to. If you are going back to `G` try playing `D` to conclude the bridge.

Assuming a return to `G` and an eight bar bridge you could try some things like:

`|Em7|Bm7|Em7|Bm7|Em7|Em7|` + `|D|D7|` ...to `G`

`|Em7|Bm7|Em7|Bm7|Em7|Em7|` + `|Am|D7|` ...to `G`

`|Em7|Em7|Bm7|Bm7|` + `|Em7|Em7|Am|C D7|` ...to `G`

Notice the variation in endings, but they all end on the dominant of `G`. Using a dominant chord is a very conventional approach to change or return to a tonal area. It's not the only way to do it, but it's common.

On the other hand you could do something more unconventional, like...

`|Em7|Bm7|Em7|Em7|Em7|Em7|` + `|Bm7|B7|` ...to `|Emaj7|`

...a digression into a totally new place: `E` major.

You can play around with the specific chord extensions and voicings, as well as how many bars to hold a chord. You have latitude to try various options in that regard. But what you really want to ask about the bridge is *where do you want it to take you harmonically?*

> ...How can I improve my knowledge about chord progression and make interesting chord progressions...

There isn't really a short cut *to understanding.* The thing to do is analyse the chord in lots and lots of songs. Ideally you should find a library with a good music score collection and look for songbooks. Combine song analysis with studying a good harmony textbook (like Kostka, Tonal Harmony. or some other college level book.) The important point being it takes time to develop deep understanding rather that just cobbling together common progressions through trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Before the question is closed for being off-topic, I want to answer question number 2.

> 2. How can I improve my knowledge about chord progression and make interesting chord progressions and not simple like this example at F
>      major scale (F,A,Dm,Bb)

I don't know how *you* can do it, but for *me*, nothing has been as beneficial as playing songs by ear in different keys. Trying to find the chords without cheating and looking at pre-made transcriptions is of course good, but if you can't find the chords even after trying, it's OK to read them. But then, *memorize* the chords, and play the song in different keys. And then make changes - substitute something with something, and see how it changes the mood, and the melodic possibilities.

Why this works for me - I think it's learning by example. If I play something without reading, I automatically learn the harmonic patterns that happen, and after playing it long enough, I start to apply the same patterns and suddenly I notice that I've learned it. Compared to this, *theoretical thinking* has not been very useful for me at all, except for getting names and terms for things. But it's always been like, (1) first learn the actual thing by example, and then (2) find names for the structural patterns, if needed. But it's never like "theory first". If theory is presented first, it's mostly meaningless mumbo jumbo. Ok, I it is *possible* to proceed even that way, but it's so much more work, it's inefficient waste of time.

So: play songs! You get to experience lots of chord, melody and rhythm patterns first-hand. To learn more interesting chord progressions, *play songs that have interesting chord progressions*. :) It's unrealistic to expect that you could actually invent or deduce things from abstract formulas.

Answer (score -3):

Chords are created from scales. Scales are merely combinations of notes.

- Go to  https://www.scalechords.com
- Select notes you are playing in your melody or scale if you are sure
- You will get chords within the selected scale, experiment with different combinations
- Make sure to select "Show Chord Tones" in settings
- I found your mentioned chords in C Major/Ionian scale
- For progressions, stick to the chords of scales (not a strict rule,just a guideline)
- always trust your ears

Comment: With the mentioned chords, G major would be a closer bet. Just because something's on the 'net...

Comment: Chords are probably better described as created from intervals above a root, and you guessed the wrong key.

Comment: I didn't go to your web page, sorry, but you shouldn't need an "app" for something as basic as this. :D Why contend with assisted helplessness instead of actually learning even a bit of something. I think you should learn basics and practice actual playing a bit more if you suggest C major for the OP's stuff. :)

Comment: I am a programmer not a musician. I am learning things from people around me like you all. I am here to see what people asks about theory. I dont know much theory/music..music is produced not calculated.. but for new things, we use learning aids. It helps to improve our understanding..I am using too. Saying it is not required is upto you. But if you you check 1 b2 b7 on guitar neck visually, you can find many chord shapes by your own, without finding chord charts.. You just please check what that link is about and can guide me on what things will be helpful. Not all people learn in one way.

Comment: piiperi - I am learning music..I have not mentioned I am a composer. Mentioned chords I saw are  in c major so I said it. I dont recognise key by ear and all.
@Michael, my key may be wrong, but those chords do exist in C Major .. Obviously intervals are the basic building blocks. Scales include Intervals as well..what you said doesnt mean what I said is wrong..I just used other words its like a=b b=c so a=c.

Comment: F# is the only difference apart from the starting note in C  and G major scales. I checked these chords with G scale, same result because F/F# chord is not used in above progression

Comment: I know where you're coming from, so to speak, and I can sympathize. But really, it is essential to be able to feel the tonal center by listening and playing. "These notes exist in this scale" does not cut it, tonal center is not about pitch sets and subsets.

Comment: About tonal center, you are right.. i will keep it in my mind. but my program works well.. will try to add a good algorithm to come up with various chord progressions!

Comment: Downvoted for "always trust your ears", then using software to guess the incorrect key. @abhijeet888 FYI, what key a piece of music is in is always subjective, and I think it'll be very difficult for you to design an algorithm to identify that. It's hard enough teaching that skill to some humans!

Comment: @user45266, Its toooooo difficult knw that very well..I will have to use AI for that ;) . and I am not telling you to produce songs with that program..its my love to music made me create that piece.. I would love to hear about that when you actually see it.. i see humans just give negative comments for things which they havent even seen. I m not a musician but I have learned things which help me understand it.. About key.. I told already that all chords are there in C major too..let it be G scale or Z scale.. I just request people who understand these things to help me improve my program..

Comment: I want to help learners see how these things work on guitar fretboard (piano will be included later)..Its like using DYNAMIC charts..no need to search for different scales and chord shapes.. you get it all there.....We dont need to be guru in something to share what we actually want to show to others..and main thing..I havent said that program guessed any KEY, its you who can see which chords actually EXISTS  in the selected scale..its simple..plzz check it and let me know